# Using fork and kill signals

Tags: c, signals, fork, kill

```
int main() {
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid > 0){
        kill(pid, SIGKILL);
        printf("a");
    }else{
        /* getppid() returns the pid
        of the parent process */
        kill(getppid(), SIGKILL);
        printf("b");
    }
}
```

The Code Snippet could have a outcome of: nothing, a, b, ab, ba

I don't understand why nothing, ab and ba are possible.

```
int a = 1;
void handler(int sig){
    a = 0;
}
void emptyhandler(int sig){
}
int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, handler);
    signal(SIGCONT, emptyhandler);

    int pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        while(a == 1)
            pause();
        printf("a");
    }else{
        kill(pid, SIGCONT);
        printf("b");
        kill(pid, SIGINT);
        printf("c");
    }
}
```

This one results in bac, bca.

Im not sure why "a process does not terminate" also valid? why would SIGINT kill it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no telling which of the child/parent that gets run first. Or they may run in parallel if you have multiple cores , or the OS might interrupt them at any point of execution and run the other child or parent process (or some entierly other process). kill() is also asynchronous, it sends the signal, and it might be handled by the receiver later, after kill() returns.

**Nothing**:  Parent gets killed right after it does `kill(pid, SIGKILL);`. Child gets killed right after it does `kill(getppid(), SIGKILL);`

**"a"**:      Child gets killed before or after it does `kill(getppid(), SIGKILL);`. Parent gets to run to completion.

**"b"**:      Parent gets killed before or after it does `kill(pid, SIGKILL);`. Child gets to run to completion.

**"ab"**      Parent gets killed right after it prints "a" (or perhaps it manages to run to completion before the child signal arrives), child gets killed after it prints "b" (or perhaps it manages to run to completion before the parent signal arrives)

**"ba"**     Same case as "ab", just that the child got scheduled to print "b" first.

Comment: For the second snippet that i just added, what does the kill(pid,SIGINT) do?  Thank you for the first part btw.

Comment: It sends the SIGINT signal to the process. SIGINT is the same signal that is sent when you hit CTRL+C. By default that signal terminates the process.

Comment: In this homework question "a process does not terminate" is still an option. If there is a SIGINT call, how is that possible?

Comment: @NeilBharatPatel Didn't your code install a handler for SIGINT ? That handler does not seem to terminate the process. So the default handler (which would terminate the process) is not run, since you have replaced it.

Answer (score 0):

*Sending* signals does not constitute any kind of synchronisation between two processes. Only sending *and* receiving a signal lets you conclude that something (e.g. printing `a`) happens after something else (e.g. printing `b`). Both signals can be "in flight" and not received by anyone.

Comment: in flight is called `pending`.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: I think "pending" is a strict subset of "in flight", but the lack of specified global synchronization semantics make it hard to be more precise than that.

Comment: could you please explain what is an in-flight signal which is not pending ?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Suppose the kernel is receiving millions of signals from thousands of processes running on hundreds of cores. I imagine that the `kill` call may return before the kernel has actually registered the signal in the target process's control structure (or decided which thread will receive the signal), so that the target may be aware of the signal via `sigpending`. But as I said, without a guarantee that the OS is serializable (which I don't believe is a given), it's hard to make this precise.

Comment: Ok you mean that it is theoretically possible. I may be wrong but I think that is a uncommon posix semantic interpretation, and possibly incorrect interpretation. `kill` is guaranteed to verify if sending is possible, etc, I would be very strange if after verifying conditions the signal would not be effectively sent... If you are right, how delivery of a signal could be notified to the sender if the delivery is asynchronous ?